# China phone after factory restart in recovery mode stuck on formating data

Tags: usb, recovery-mode, boot-loop

Can´t get to recovery mode, can´t connect via USB becouse it still rebooting. And it says Fromating /data....
mount system/ error

Can somebody help me?

Comment: can you please provide your device name?

Comment: It is Lenovo from china Lenovo_S898t+

Answer (score 1):

Please flash stock rom using smart phone flash tool stock rom for your device is here http://androidxda.com/download-lenovo-stock-rom-models

and direct link is here https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3H1waZx5Veqa3ItOG1xZWM4U28

please refer http://androidxda.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool for flashing stock rom

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did find all that things but my self and read all about flashing phone, but my problem is that I cant connect phone to PC becouse when I connect it the phone is always rebooting if there is no batery inside, or is in recovery loop and writing formating/data... mount system/ error. So the PC recognize connection of phone and connected it an in one second phone reboot and rebooting all over again, or connect and disconect and showing recovery loop.